# How to call an array method in main class

Tags: java, arrays

Vol is an array that should produce 3 different volumes. I want to call it in the main/driver file so it can print the resulting volume to the screen
class:

Comment: Your return type is not an array

Comment: @Kamushek I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: what is k and vol, you are looping volume with k size

Comment: Vol is in the code you wrote; just short form for volume. And K is just another variable that also has 3 values; can be ignored. I will update code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the java syntax. This [source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/#:%7E:text=First%2C%20you%20must%20declare%20a,all%20arrays%20are%20dynamically%20allocated.) will help you.

You are aiming to return two different types of java. Java doesn't allow that. Java methods can only return one result (void, a primitive, or an object).

The proper way to do this calculating the volume with a single method and when we need to calculate all volumes then we can use that method to iterate over the array

```
//Single calculation

public double calculateSingleVolume( double diameter, double height){
 double vol = ((Math.PI)*Math.pow(diameter[i], 2)*(height[i]))/4; //Vol = pi*(D^2)/4 * L;
return vol
}


// Calculate on Array of diameters and heights
public double[] calculateArrayVolume(double[] diameters, double[] heights){
 double[] volumes = new double[diamters.length];
 for(int i = 0; i< diameters.length; i++){
  volumes[i] = calculateSingleVolume(diameters[i], heights[i]);
 }
 return volumes;
}

public double[] calculate_Cp2019(doulbe []volumes)
    {
        double [] Cp2019 = new double[volumes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < volumes.length; i++)
        {
            Cp2019[i] = (616/397) * volumes[i]
      }
       return Cp2019;

//Now you can use above method to calculate volumes for array of diametes and heights

public static void main(String[] args){
 double [] diameters = {2, 2.4, 1.5};
 double [] heights = {10, 22, 32};
 double[] volumes = calculateArrayVolume(diameters,heights);
 double[]  cp2019 =calculate_Cp2019(volumes);
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cp2019));
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I get an error in 'return Vol' - the last line.

Comment: If you want to return Java array or java double type object

Comment: It says 'Array initializer is not allowed here' for return {Vol[i]};

Comment: yes Lisa, we need to iniliize with new keyword lets check

Comment: Don't forget, you will get a double array from the method. Hit me if u have any issue

Comment: Thank you. But how would I call the method in another method. Example: Math.log(this.calculateVolume() no longer works

Comment: use a for loop to iterate the array elements and call it one by one

Comment: I am asking why you are using second for loop in this function

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I took out for (int i=0; i<diameter.length; i++)
           return new double[]{Vol[i]};

Comment: Thank you. How would I use Vol in another method: 
        for (int i = 0; i < this.K_values.length; i++)
        {
            Cp2019 = Math.pow(10, (K_values[0] + (K_values[1]* Math.log(this.calculateVolume())) + (K_values[2]* Math.pow(Math.log(this.calculateVolume()), 2))));
        }
        return Cp2019;

Comment: check the last updated version

Comment: Thank you. Please view my updated question with specific parameters.

Comment: You can calculate volumes then using caculate method to calculate the Cp2019, I am just printing those values in console

Comment: But when I try to print out the volume in a different class is doesn't work: System.out.println("This is the volume for Option 1: " + calculateVolume(Vol[0]));

Comment: Hi! I have updated my code. I appreciate your help. @rcvaram

Comment: I have some questions and really need help. Please message me.

Comment: I messaged on linkedin. Please respond.